# Why does the HUD's chunk coordinates information have 3 numbers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I press F3 to turn on the HUD, my chunk line says something like this.

```
Chunk: 8 6 0 in -17 4 3
```

My understanding is that I am standing on block `8 6 0` in the `-17 4 3` chunk. By shouldn't chunks be 2 dimensional since they go from bedrock to sky level? Why are there 3 numbers?

<sup>Minecraft 1.8.1</sup>

Comment: Can't test right now, but do all three numbers change when you move around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is labeled as "Chunk", it is actually showing the chunk **section** (16*16*16) that you are in. The second number is the y value of the section.